# How can I apply all the sql files in a directory?

Tags: sql, ant

We currently run a specific SQL script as part of our Ant deploy process.

What we'd like to do is change this so we run all SQL scripts in a given directory.  We can't figure out how to get this directory listing in Ant and iterate through the list and run each SQL script.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Note: we currently run the sql file by using the Ant `exec` task that runs "`call sqlplus ${id}/${pw}@${db.instance} @${file}`"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend using the Ant [`SQL` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html).  You can then specify with the following:

```
<sql
    driver="org.database.jdbcDriver"
    url="jdbc:database-url"
    userid="sa"
    password="pass">
  <path>
    <fileset dir=".">
      <include name="data*.sql"/>
    </fileset>
  <path>
</sql>
```

Comment: Be aware, the ant sql task 'chokes' on function declarations.
I dont yet know how to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

i am doing basically the same thing on an oracle database.. but using sqlplus and the apply task. this allows the scripts to contain DDL statements.

would obviously only work where you have a command line program to use.
using ant 1.8.2  and antcontrib.

i have defined a few macros for use.. (see below)  and then just call like

```
<compile_sql connectstring="${db.connect_string}"  >
        <filelist dir="${db_proc.dir}" files="specific_file.sql" />
        <fileset dir="${db_proc.dir}" includes="wildcard*.pks" />
        <fileset dir="${db_proc.dir}" includes="wildcard*.pkb" />
</compile_sql>
```

the macros are as follows

```
<macrodef name="compile_sql">
    <attribute name="connectstring" />
    <attribute name="dirtostart" default=""/>
    <attribute name="arg1" default=""/>
    <element name="sqllist" implicit="true" description="filesetlist of sql to run"/>
    <sequential>
        <check_missing_files>
            <sqllist/>
        </check_missing_files>
        <apply executable="${sqlplus.exe}"  failonerror="true" verbose="true" skipemptyfilesets="true" ignoremissing="false" dir="@{dirtostart}">
            <arg value="-L"/>
            <arg value="@{connectstring}"/>
            <srcfile prefix="@" />
            <sqllist/>
            <arg value="@{arg1}"/>
            <redirector>
            <globmapper id="sqlout.mapper" 
               from="*"
               to="*.out"/>
            </redirector>
        </apply>

    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

and

```
<macrodef name="check_missing_files">
    <element name="checkfilelist" implicit="true" description="filelist of files to check for existance"/>
    <sequential>
    <restrict id="missing.files" xmlns:rsel="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors">
        <resources>
            <checkfilelist/>
        </resources>
        <rsel:not>
            <rsel:exists/>
        </rsel:not>
    </restrict>
    <fail message="These files are missing: ${ant.refid:missing.files}"  >
        <condition >
            <length string="${ant.refid:missing.files}" when="greater" length="0" />
        </condition>
    </fail>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```